# Make a copy of the files in a directory but save them as a different file type

Tags: matlab, directory, copy, save, file-type

Is it possible to list all of the files in a directory of a certain file type, and then save them in the same directory but as a separate file type using MatLab?

In my case, I have 144 files saved as in a .fig format, but I would like to copy them as a .tif format so that I don't have to go and change each file manually.

I know I can list all the files in my directory using the `dir` function and I guess I could simply run `for` loop with `i=1:length(dir)` but I don't know how to isolate the files of a specific file type. I don't see filetype as a field name on the mathworks website for `dir`.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list only files of type `.fig`:

```
files = dir('*.fig');
```

You can then loop over the names:

```
for k = 1:numel(files)
    filename = files(k).name;
    % do something with filename
end
```

Comment: is there a built-in function where I can copy it as a different type, or do I need load the file, and use `saveas`?

Comment: I don't think there is a builtin function for that. I'd load the file and use `saveas`. To load faster, you can maybe use `openfig(...,'invisible')` (I haven't tried it)

Comment: I would also recommend using `fileparts` to get the filename without the extension and then you can save it using `saveas` with appropriate extension.